# Ext js change a toolbar item

Tags: javascript, extjs, toolbar

It should be possible to change items on a toolbar, but somehow changes are never displayed. Somehow something is wrong, and I can't find it. I also can't change text or a button state neither.

I need to change the 'all' checkbox. Changing is done in our controller by:

```
Ext.widget('gw_main_signals').down('#all').setValue(false);
```

and the view is (shortened):

```
Ext.define('GW.view.main.Signals', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.gw_main_signals',
    store: 'signal.Signals',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.bbar = Ext.    
        create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        store: this.store,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: '{0} - {1} / {2}',
        emptyMsg: ''
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    autoScroll: true,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        itemId: 'signalToolbar',
        layout: {
            overflowHandler: 'Menu'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'label',
            html: bundle.getMsg('state') + ':',    
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: bundle.getMsg('new'),
            itemId: 'new',
            enableToggle: true,
            pressed: true
            // pressed by default
        }, '-', {
            // xtype: 'button',
            // xtype: 'menucheckitem',
            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
            boxLabel: bundle.getMsg('all'),
            itemId: 'all',
        }]
    }],
    columns: [...],
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have You try put `Ext.widget('gw_main_signals').down('#all')` in `console.log` to see if the checkboxes are realy founed?

Comment: `Ext.widget` creates a new instance.

Comment: Uch tnx, I accidently used Ext.widget instead of Ext.getCmp('id'), somehow I mix these two up in my mind. Super thanks!